# How to bind value to angularjs directive?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working on a directive to create a custom dropdown. I have managed to bring the directive code to get it replaced.

Below is the directive tag in the `html`

```
<dropdown placeholder="Country.." list="count" selected="item" property="name"></dropdown>
```

Below is the html template that replaces the directive tag

```
<div class="dropdown-container" ng-class="{ show: listVisible }">
<div class="dropdown-list">
    <div>
        <div ng-repeat="item in list" ng-click="select(item)" ng-class="{ selected: isSelected(item) }">
            <span>{{property !== undefined ? item[property] : item}}</span>
            <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is the angularjs directive

```
App.directive("dropdown", function ($rootScope) {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: "/app/dropdownTemplate.html",
    scope: {
        placeholder: "@",
        list: "=",
        selected: "=",
        property: "@"
    },
    link: function (scope) {
        scope.listVisible = false;
        scope.isPlaceholder = true;

        scope.select = function (item) {
            scope.isPlaceholder = false;
            scope.selected = item;
        };

        scope.isSelected = function (item) {
            return item[scope.property] === scope.selected[scope.property];
        };

        scope.show = function () {
            scope.listVisible = true;
        };

        $rootScope.$on("documentClicked", function (inner, target) {
            console.log($(target[0]).is(".dropdown-display.clicked") || $(target[0]).parents(".dropdown-display.clicked").length > 0);
            if (!$(target[0]).is(".dropdown-display.clicked") && !$(target[0]).parents(".dropdown-display.clicked").length > 0)
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.listVisible = false;
                });
        });

        scope.$watch("selected", function (value) {
            scope.isPlaceholder = scope.selected[scope.property] === undefined;
            scope.display = scope.selected[scope.property];
        });
    }
}
});
```

I am trying to get the list of countries from another controller whose function is as follows,

```
addressService.getCountries().success(function (response) {
    angular.copy(response, $scope.list);
}
```

How do I bind the values from the controller to my directive when the page loads?

EDIT: What do I do as the directive loads before the function `addressService.getCountries()` gets called?

Comment: Just bind `$scope.list` to another property in your directive `scope {}` using two-way binding (`=`)?

Comment: Use a service to pass the data

Comment: @NexusDuck Could you please elaborate? I am unable to comprehend how to add property to `scope { }`

Comment: Like  scope: {
       country list: //something here<br>
        placeholder: "@",
        list: "=",
        selected: "=",
        property: "@"
    },

Comment: @Kailas I am still not able to bind the value from `addressService.getCountries()`.

Comment: did you try giving the directive the list from the controller? `list="list"`

Answer (score 0):

you can make a factory that will be useful throughout project to make to make a variable accessible whenever and wherever, in any controller or in any directive you want to use that variable you can easily access

this is how we can make factory,

```
(function() {
"use strict";
angular.module('dataModule',[])
.factory('datafactory',function(){
 return {
 credentials : {},
 };
 });
 })();
```

After making this factory you can inject this module in your module and this factory in your controller

whenever you want you can use this like

```
addressService.getCountries().success(function (response) {
datafactory.country = response
}
```

in your controller

```
$scope.myvar =datafactory.country
```

in future you use this factory for any such variable that will be accessible everywhere for example you want to store list of state globally

```
datafactory.state =["abc","def","xyz"]
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Will implement this technique from the start of next project.

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why you are returning `credentials : {},`

Comment: credentials is of no use in this scenario it is just dummy object here, that we return some object, we can remove that or keep it no issues, it is just a dummy object here

even if we remove our factory will look like this and it will work fine

    (function() {
    "use strict";
    angular.module('dataModule',[])
.factory('datafactory',function(){
 return {
 };
 });
 })();